# UIWebView Javascript retain variable values between function calls

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am using UIwebview to run some javascript, I want to retain a variable value between function call on click of a button from iOS native.

code snipped which i am using.

```
var MyApp_SearchResultCount = 0;
var currSelected = 0;
var prevSelected = 0; 

function jump(howHigh){

    //this.prevVal = this.currentVal; 
    //this.currentVal = this.currentVal + 1; 

    //************** STARTS ****************//

    //alert(window.currSelected);

    //************** ENDS  *****************//


    prevSelected = currSelected;
    currSelected = currSelected + howHigh;
    alert("currSelected" + currSelected);
  }
```

currSelected always remains 1, irrelevant of how many times jump method is called.

Please help
Thanks 
djrecker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it to increment doing the following:

1. Create a simple Webview and a property for it
2. Create a property for i of type int
3. Create a button which is clicked and executes the following method

In your case, the increment is happening in the javascript code, but that state is not known to the class. You need to be able to create dynamic Javascript by passing some arguments.

```
-(IBAction)runJS{ 
    NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert(%d)",self.i];

    NSString *string = [wv stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];


    self.i=self.i+1;
}
```

Comment: Hey Srikanth what if i want to pass some value from javascript to native back....any idea please help. thanks djrecker

Comment: NSString *string = [wv stringByEvaluatingJavaScript...] does exactly that. You can send back a string and then use it accordingly.

Comment: What if i want to return a int value..? any suggestions, please suggest.

Comment: I think you have to type cast the returned value. [string intValue] etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)runJS{
    NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"function abcd(){var x=%i; return x;} abcd();",self.i];

    NSString *string = [wv stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];


    self.i=self.i+1;

    NSLog(@"The returned value is %@",string);
}
```

You can infact define a function and call it or what ever. The return value of the function is captured in the return string. I added another answer because it did not allow me to do proper formatting of code in the comment field